"The package deployment failed because its publisher is not in the unsigned namespace." while installing self signed msix
I am developing a msix. My development process is,

Build the app
Package the app as an msix
Self sign it
Install and test

But while installing the app I suddenly started getting

and if I use Add-AppxPackage I get
Add-AppxPackage -Path "C:\PathToMsix\MsixName.msix" -AllowUnsigned


Add-AppxPackage: Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073D2C, The
package deployment failed because its publisher is not in the unsigned
namespace.
Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on Package
MicrosoftCorporationII.PackageName_1.0.0.3_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe from:
(MsixName_x64_Release_1.0.0.3.msix)  failed with error 0x80073D2C. See
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
deployment issues.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId]
03e8ba76-9705-0007-55c0-fe030597da01 in the Event Log or use the
command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID
03e8ba76-9705-0007-55c0-fe030597da01

